# Maven Surefire: Is it possible to get test result summary on console during execution

Tags: maven, gradle, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a test suite that takes hours to complete. It would be very helpful if I could get a runtime summary of the test execution.

I want something like [gradle logger plugin](https://github.com/radarsh/gradle-test-logger-plugin/blob/develop/docs/images/standard.gif). As shown in the link, the console output of this plugin shows test results on the console for each test, and as it happens.

- Does the Maven ecosystem have a similar plugin
- If not then is there a way to achieve this using surefire configuration?

Comment: First if your tests taking hours that means you are running integration tests which are usually done by maven-failsafe-plugin and not by maven-surefire-plugin... ....

Comment: Yes, you are right, these are integration tests. I'll recheck the facts in the above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are expecting because if I run my build with tests it looks similar like this:

```
[INFO] --- surefire:3.1.2:test (default-test) @ kata-fraction ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Limits
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.073 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Limits
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Pow
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Pow
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Addition
[INFO] Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Addition
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Subtraction
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Subtraction
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Divide
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Divide
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Multiplikation
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Multiplikation
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Normalizing
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.001 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Normalizing
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$InvalideValues
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.005 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$InvalideValues
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Verification
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.304 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Verification
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$CompareTo
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.004 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$CompareTo
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Signum
[INFO] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Signum
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Negate
[INFO] Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$Negate
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$DoubleValue
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$DoubleValue
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$BigDecimalValue
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest$BigDecimalValue
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.421 s -- in com.soebes.kata.fraction.FractionIntegerTest
[INFO] Running com.soebes.kata.fraction.dynamic.DynamicFractionTest
 ....
```

That's continous output????